# iphone audio streaming

Tags: iphone

i'm developing an application which uses audio streaming. For streaming audio from internet i'm using the AudioStreamer class. The audio streamer has 
four state isPlaying, isPaused ,isWaiting, and isIdle . My problem is that when the audio streamer is in the state "isWaiting" and at that time if i get a phone call Audio queue fails giving the error "Audio queue start failed." Any has solution for this? help....

Answer (score 1):

An interruption - such as receiving a call - will deactivate the Audio Session. It's up to you to, in your interruption handler, re-activate the Audio Session by calling AudioSessionSetActive(true).

Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) for details of the interruption handler.

Having said that, I'll assume that you're using [mattgallagher's library](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer). The thing to do is put a breakpoint in AudioStreamer.m on line 949 (the line after "err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);" in -[AudioStreamer pause].

If err == kAudioSessionNotActiveError then my theory's right, and you need to call restart the audio session. Perhaps something like this (but I've only only ever glanced through this code so perhaps there's a better way of solving the problem):

```
else if (state == AS_PAUSED)
{
  err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
  if (err) {
    err = AudioSessionSetActive(true);
    if (err) {
      [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_START_FAILED];
      return;
    } else {
      err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
      if (err) {
        [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_START_FAILED];
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```